# Grabbing content of external site CSS class. (steam store)

Tags: php, laravel, steam, domxpath

I have been playing around with this code for a while but cant get it to work properly.
My goal is to display or maybe even create a table with ID's of grabbed data from the steam store for my own website and game library. the class is 'game_area_description'
This is a study project of mine.

So i tried to get the table using the following code.

```
@section('selectedGame');
<?php 
$url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/'.$game->appID."/";
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${url}");


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="game_area_description"]/a');
$link = $dom->saveHTML($elements->item(0));
echo $link;


?>
@endsection;
```

I am using Laravel by the way.

In some other cases i can get another piece of the website.

```
$url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/'.$game->appID."/";

$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="game_description_snippet">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo "<p>${second_step[0]}</p>";
```

Here it just takes the excerpt of the webpage which works in some cases.

Here is the biggest issue, other than not beeing able to get all the information where i get an error `$first_step[1]`is not valid.
Is some CORE issue.
See the webpage loads an age check in some cases like "Batman Arkham knight". the user needs to either log in or verify their age first.
Keeping me from using the second block of code.

But the first gives me all kinds of errors as the screenshot shows.

Anyone know of a way to grab this part of the page?
Where the description of the game is?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how json_decode() works in PHP -> https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=911400 which is much more easy to parse then html

Comment: You also want to make a import script with data from https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/ (large file)  then you can use your table to search games to steam appid

Comment: Thanks Raymond, 
Colleague also got the API from somewhere, it;'s not in the documentation from what i have seen. 
Issue resolved 
thanks for the tips.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. 
Code is now working with this API. 

```@section('selectedGame');
<div class="container border">
    <!-- Content here -->
  
<?php 

$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=".$game->appID;
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$gameID = $game->appID;
$gameDescr = $parsed[$gameID]['data']['about_the_game'];

echo $gameDescr;
?>
</div>
@endsection;```

Comment: "Grabbing content of external site CSS class. (steam store)" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve your problem? How is this related to Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was in the comments.

apparently steam has some undocumented API's .
here is the code ( with bootstrap CSS).
That i used and going ti implement in my migration tables and seeder

```
@section('selectedGame');
<div class="container border">
    <!-- Content here -->
  
<?php 

$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=".$game->appID;
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$gameID = $game->appID;
$gameDescr = $parsed[$gameID]['data']['about_the_game'];

echo $gameDescr;
?>
</div>
@endsection;
```

[image]